# REST API call to fetch attachment from salesforce is showing Binary response. How can i covert this Binary response to the Original file?

Tags: rest-api, attachment, files

[image]

I am trying to extract a file from Salesforce through REST API call. I am getting the Respone in Binary File. How can i covert this Binary response to the Original file?

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by original file? Is returned binary data incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Postman documentation on handling responses](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/responses/):

> If your API endpoint returns an image, Postman will detect and render it automatically. For binary response types, you should select “Send and download” which will let you save the response to your hard disk. You can then view it using the appropriate viewer. This gives you the flexibility to test audio files, PDFs, zip files, or anything that the API throws at you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears based on the "magic number" header `PK` that this is probably a ZIP archive, or some file type that is stored as a ZIP bundle like `docx`.

You would need to download the file and decompress it (if it is indeed a ZIP archive) or open it in the appropriate application (if it is a ZIP-bundled file type).

Comment: Thank you and i was able to save it as ZIp file and it worked for me.